# MLflow S3UploadFailedError: Failed to upload

Tags: python, mysql, docker, minio, mlflow

I've created with docker a MinioS3 artifact storage and a MySQL backend storage using the next Docker Compose:

```
    version: '3.8'
    services:
        db:
           environment:
              - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
              - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
              - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
              - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
           expose:
              - '3306'        
           volumes:
              - '(path)/server_backend:/var/lib/mysql '
           image: 'mysql'
           container_name: db

        storage:
            environment:
                - MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=${MINIO_USR}
                - MINIO_SECRET_KEY=${MINIO_PASS}
            expose:
                - '9000'
            ports:
                - '9000:9000'        
            depends_on:
                - db
            command: server /data
            volumes:
                - '(path)/server_artifact:/data'
            image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2021-02-14T04-01-33Z
            container_name: MinIO

        mlflow:
            build: ./mlflow
            environment:
                - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${MINIO_USR}
                - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${MINIO_PASS}       
            expose:
                - '5000'
            ports:
                - '5000:5000'
            depends_on:
                - storage                       
            image: 'mlflow:Dockerfile'
            container_name: server
```

The Mlflow server docker was created using the next Dockerfile:

```
    FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
    WORKDIR /usr/src/app
    RUN pip install cryptography mlflow psycopg2-binary boto3 pymysql
    ENV MLFLOW_S3_ENDPOINT_URL=http://storage:9000
    CMD mlflow server \
        --backend-store-uri mysql+pymysql://MLFLOW:temporal@db:3306/DBMLFLOW \
        --default-artifact-root s3://artifacts \
        --host 0.0.0.0
```

The credantials are defined in a `.env` file.

The results of the `docker-compose` up command:

```
    [+] Running 21/22
     - mlflow Error                                                                                                                              5.6s
     - storage Pulled                                                                                                                           36.9s
       - a6b97b4963f5 Pull complete                                                                                                             24.6s
       - 13948a011eec Pull complete                                                                                                             24.7s
       - 40cdef9976a6 Pull complete                                                                                                             24.7s
       - f47162848743 Pull complete                                                                                                             24.8s
       - 5f2758d8e94c Pull complete                                                                                                             24.9s
       - c2950439edb8 Pull complete                                                                                                             25.0s
       - 1b08f8a15998 Pull complete                                                                                                             30.7s
     - db Pulled                                                                                                                                45.8s
       - 07aded7c29c6 Already exists                                                                                                             0.0s
       - f68b8cbd22de Pull complete                                                                                                              0.7s
       - 30c1754a28c4 Pull complete                                                                                                              2.1s
       - 1b7cb4d6fe05 Pull complete                                                                                                              2.2s
       - 79a41dc56b9a Pull complete                                                                                                              2.3s
       - 00a75e3842fb Pull complete                                                                                                              6.7s
       - b36a6919c217 Pull complete                                                                                                              6.8s
       - 635b0b84d686 Pull complete                                                                                                              6.8s
       - 6d24c7242d02 Pull complete                                                                                                             39.4s
       - 5be6c5edf16f Pull complete                                                                                                             39.5s
       - cb35eac1242c Pull complete                                                                                                             39.5s
       - a573d4e1c407 Pull complete                                                                                                             39.6s
    [+] Building 1.4s (7/7) FINISHED
     => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                         0.0s
     => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                          0.0s
     => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                            0.0s
     => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                              0.0s
     => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.8-slim-buster                                                                    1.3s
     => [1/3] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.8-slim-buster@sha256:13a3f2bffb4b18ff7eda2763a3b0ba316dd82e548f52ea8b4fd11c94b97afa7d              0.0s
     => CACHED [2/3] WORKDIR /usr/src/app                                                                                                        0.0s
     => CACHED [3/3] RUN pip install cryptography mlflow psycopg2-binary boto3 pymysql                                                           0.0s
     => exporting to image                                                                                                                       0.0s
     => => exporting layers                                                                                                                      0.0s
     => => writing image sha256:76d4e4462b5c7c1826734e59a54488b56660de0dd5ecc188c308202608a8f20b                                                 0.0s
     => => naming to docker.io/library/mlflow:Dockerfile                                                                                         0.0s
    
    Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
    [+] Running 3/3
     - Container db  Created                                                                                                       0.5s
     - Container MinIO      Created                                                                                                       0.1s
     - Container server     Created                                                                                                       0.1s
    Attaching to server, MinIO, db
    db  | 2021-10-06 12:12:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.26-1debian10 started.
    db  | 2021-10-06 12:12:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
    db  | 2021-10-06 12:12:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.26-1debian10 started.
    db  | 2021-10-06 12:12:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:12:57.679527Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.26) initializing of server in progress as process 44
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:12:57.687748Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:12:58.230036Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:12:59.888820Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:12:59.889102Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:12:59.997461Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
    MinIO      | Attempting encryption of all config, IAM users and policies on MinIO backend
    MinIO      | Endpoint: http://172.18.0.3:9000  http://127.0.0.1:9000
    MinIO      |
    MinIO      | Browser Access:
    MinIO      |    http://172.18.0.3:9000  http://127.0.0.1:9000
    MinIO      |
    MinIO      | Object API (Amazon S3 compatible):
    MinIO      |    Go:         https://docs.min.io/docs/golang-client-quickstart-guide
    MinIO      |    Java:       https://docs.min.io/docs/java-client-quickstart-guide
    MinIO      |    Python:     https://docs.min.io/docs/python-client-quickstart-guide
    MinIO      |    JavaScript: https://docs.min.io/docs/javascript-client-quickstart-guide
    MinIO      |    .NET:       https://docs.min.io/docs/dotnet-client-quickstart-guide
    server     | 2021/10/06 12:13:02 WARNING mlflow.store.db.utils: SQLAlchemy engine could not be created. The following exception is caught.
    server     | (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
    server     | (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
    server     | Operation will be retried in 0.1 seconds
    server     | 2021/10/06 12:13:02 WARNING mlflow.store.db.utils: SQLAlchemy engine could not be created. The following exception is caught.
    server     | (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
    server     | (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
    server     | Operation will be retried in 0.3 seconds
    server     | 2021/10/06 12:13:02 WARNING mlflow.store.db.utils: SQLAlchemy engine could not be created. The following exception is caught.
    server     | (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
    server     | (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
    server     | Operation will be retried in 0.7 seconds
    server     | 2021/10/06 12:13:03 WARNING mlflow.store.db.utils: SQLAlchemy engine could not be created. The following exception is caught.
    server     | (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
    server     | (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
    server     | Operation will be retried in 1.5 seconds
    db  | 2021-10-06 12:13:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
    db  | 2021-10-06 12:13:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:13:04.422603Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.26) starting as process 93
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:13:04.439806Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:13:04.575773Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:13:04.827307Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:13:04.827865Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:13:04.832827Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:13:04.834132Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:13:04.841629Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:13:04.855748Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:13:04.855801Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.26'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
    db  | 2021-10-06 12:13:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
    server     | 2021/10/06 12:13:05 WARNING mlflow.store.db.utils: SQLAlchemy engine could not be created. The following exception is caught.
    server     | (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
    server     | (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
    server     | Operation will be retried in 3.1 seconds
    db  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
    db  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
    db  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
    db  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
    db  | 2021-10-06 12:13:06+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database DBMLFLOW
    db  | 2021-10-06 12:13:06+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user MLFLOW
    db  | 2021-10-06 12:13:06+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Giving user MLFLOW access to schema DBMLFLOW
    db  |
    db  | 2021-10-06 12:13:06+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:13:06.948482Z 13 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user root. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.26).
    server     | 2021/10/06 12:13:08 WARNING mlflow.store.db.utils: SQLAlchemy engine could not be created. The following exception is caught.
    server     | (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
    server     | (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
    server     | Operation will be retried in 6.3 seconds
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:13:08.716131Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.26)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
    db  | 2021-10-06 12:13:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped
    db  |
    db  | 2021-10-06 12:13:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
    db  |
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:13:09.159115Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.26) starting as process 1
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:13:09.167405Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:13:09.298925Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:13:09.488958Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:13:09.489087Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:13:09.489934Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:13:09.490169Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:13:09.494728Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:13:09.509856Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
    db  | 2021-10-06T12:13:09.509982Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.26'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
    db  | mbind: Operation not permitted
    server     | 2021/10/06 12:13:14 INFO mlflow.store.db.utils: Creating initial MLflow database tables...
    server     | 2021/10/06 12:13:14 INFO mlflow.store.db.utils: Updating database tables
    server     | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.
    server     | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
    server     | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade  -> 451aebb31d03, add metric step
    server     | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 451aebb31d03 -> 90e64c465722, migrate user column to tags
    server     | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 90e64c465722 -> 181f10493468, allow nulls for metric values
    server     | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 181f10493468 -> df50e92ffc5e, Add Experiment Tags Table
    server     | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade df50e92ffc5e -> 7ac759974ad8, Update run tags with larger limit
    server     | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 7ac759974ad8 -> 89d4b8295536, create latest metrics table
    server     | INFO  [89d4b8295536_create_latest_metrics_table_py] Migration complete!
    server     | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 89d4b8295536 -> 2b4d017a5e9b, add model registry tables to db
    server     | INFO  [2b4d017a5e9b_add_model_registry_tables_to_db_py] Adding registered_models and model_versions tables to database.
    server     | INFO  [2b4d017a5e9b_add_model_registry_tables_to_db_py] Migration complete!
    server     | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 2b4d017a5e9b -> cfd24bdc0731, Update run status constraint with killed
    server     | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade cfd24bdc0731 -> 0a8213491aaa, drop_duplicate_killed_constraint
    server     | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 0a8213491aaa -> 728d730b5ebd, add registered model tags table
    server     | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 728d730b5ebd -> 27a6a02d2cf1, add model version tags table
    server     | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 27a6a02d2cf1 -> 84291f40a231, add run_link to model_version
    server     | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 84291f40a231 -> a8c4a736bde6, allow nulls for run_id
    server     | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade a8c4a736bde6 -> 39d1c3be5f05, add_is_nan_constraint_for_metrics_tables_if_necessary
    server     | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 39d1c3be5f05 -> c48cb773bb87, reset_default_value_for_is_nan_in_metrics_table_for_mysql
    server     | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.
    server     | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
    db  | mbind: Operation not permitted
    server     | [2021-10-06 12:13:16 +0000] [17] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
    server     | [2021-10-06 12:13:16 +0000] [17] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (17)
    server     | [2021-10-06 12:13:16 +0000] [17] [INFO] Using worker: sync
    server     | [2021-10-06 12:13:16 +0000] [19] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19
    server     | [2021-10-06 12:13:16 +0000] [20] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20
    server     | [2021-10-06 12:13:16 +0000] [21] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 21
    server     | [2021-10-06 12:13:16 +0000] [22] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22
```

It makes me suspect because on the second line appears `- mlflow Error` but I think that this is why the other builds haven't finished.

Then I've set my environment variables on the client to create the information flow between my script and the storages:

```
    os.environ['MLFLOW_S3_ENDPOINT_URL'] = 'http://localhost:9000/'
    os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = 'key'
    os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = 'pw'
    
    remote_server_uri = "http://localhost:5000/" # server URI
    mlflow.set_tracking_uri(remote_server_uri)
    
    mlflow.set_experiment("mnist_mLflow_demo")
```

finally I trained a TensorFlow network and I didn't have problems storing parameters and metrics but gave me some warnings (referring to next error). But the model haven't been auto log, so I tried to do it manually:

```
    with mlflow.start_run(run_name = "test0") as run:
    
        mlflow.keras.log_model(model2, 'model2')

    mlflow.end_run()
```

It dosen't work and it gives me the next INFO (but essencialy an error):

```
    INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: (path)\Temp\tmpgr5eaha2\model\data\model\assets
    INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: (path)\Temp\tmpgr5eaha2\model\data\model\assets
    2021/10/06 14:16:00 ERROR mlflow.utils.environment: Encountered an unexpected error while inferring pip requirements (model URI: (path)\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgr5eaha2\model, flavor: keras)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "(path)\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\environment.py", line 212, in infer_pip_requirements
        return _infer_requirements(model_uri, flavor)
      File "(path)\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\requirements_utils.py", line 263, in _infer_requirements
        modules = _capture_imported_modules(model_uri, flavor)
      File "(path)\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\requirements_utils.py", line 221, in _capture_imported_modules
        _run_command(
      File "(path)\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\requirements_utils.py", line 163, in _run_command
        stderr = stderr.decode("utf-8")
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 349: invalid continuation byte
```

And the next error:

```
    ClientError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    ~\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\boto3\s3\transfer.py in upload_file(self, filename, bucket, key, callback, extra_args)
        278         try:
    --> 279             future.result()
        280         # If a client error was raised, add the backwards compatibility layer
    
    ~\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\futures.py in result(self)
        105             # out of this and propogate the exception.
    --> 106             return self._coordinator.result()
        107         except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
    
    ~\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\futures.py in result(self)
        264         if self._exception:
    --> 265             raise self._exception
        266         return self._result
    
    ~\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\tasks.py in __call__(self)
        125             if not self._transfer_coordinator.done():
    --> 126                 return self._execute_main(kwargs)
        127         except Exception as e:
    
    ~\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\tasks.py in _execute_main(self, kwargs)
        149 
    --> 150         return_value = self._main(**kwargs)
        151         # If the task is the final task, then set the TransferFuture's
    
    ~\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\upload.py in _main(self, client, fileobj, bucket, key, extra_args)
        693         with fileobj as body:
    --> 694             client.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Body=body, **extra_args)
        695 
    
    ~\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
        385             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
    --> 386             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
        387 
    
    ~\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
        704             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
    --> 705             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
        706         else:
    
    ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the PutObject operation: The Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    S3UploadFailedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
    C:\Users\FCAIZA~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7164/2476247499.py in <module>
          1 with mlflow.start_run(run_name = "test0") as run:
          2 
    ----> 3     mlflow.keras.log_model(model2, 'model2')
          4 
          5 mlflow.end_run()
    
    ~\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mlflow\keras.py in log_model(keras_model, artifact_path, conda_env, custom_objects, keras_module, registered_model_name, signature, input_example, await_registration_for, pip_requirements, extra_pip_requirements, **kwargs)
        402             mlflow.keras.log_model(keras_model, "models")
        403     """
    --> 404     Model.log(
        405         artifact_path=artifact_path,
        406         flavor=mlflow.keras,
    
    ~\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mlflow\models\model.py in log(cls, artifact_path, flavor, registered_model_name, await_registration_for, **kwargs)
        186             mlflow_model = cls(artifact_path=artifact_path, run_id=run_id)
        187             flavor.save_model(path=local_path, mlflow_model=mlflow_model, **kwargs)
    --> 188             mlflow.tracking.fluent.log_artifacts(local_path, artifact_path)
        189             try:
        190                 mlflow.tracking.fluent._record_logged_model(mlflow_model)
    
    ~\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\fluent.py in log_artifacts(local_dir, artifact_path)
        582     """
        583     run_id = _get_or_start_run().info.run_id
    --> 584     MlflowClient().log_artifacts(run_id, local_dir, artifact_path)
        585 
        586 
    
    ~\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\client.py in log_artifacts(self, run_id, local_dir, artifact_path)
        975             is_dir: True
        976         """
    --> 977         self._tracking_client.log_artifacts(run_id, local_dir, artifact_path)
        978 
        979     @contextlib.contextmanager
    
    ~\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\_tracking_service\client.py in log_artifacts(self, run_id, local_dir, artifact_path)
        332         :param artifact_path: If provided, the directory in ``artifact_uri`` to write to.
        333         """
    --> 334         self._get_artifact_repo(run_id).log_artifacts(local_dir, artifact_path)
        335 
        336     def list_artifacts(self, run_id, path=None):
    
    ~\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mlflow\store\artifact\s3_artifact_repo.py in log_artifacts(self, local_dir, artifact_path)
        102                 upload_path = posixpath.join(dest_path, rel_path)
        103             for f in filenames:
    --> 104                 self._upload_file(
        105                     s3_client=s3_client,
        106                     local_file=os.path.join(root, f),
    
    ~\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mlflow\store\artifact\s3_artifact_repo.py in _upload_file(self, s3_client, local_file, bucket, key)
         78         if environ_extra_args is not None:
         79             extra_args.update(environ_extra_args)
    ---> 80         s3_client.upload_file(Filename=local_file, Bucket=bucket, Key=key, ExtraArgs=extra_args)
         81 
         82     def log_artifact(self, local_file, artifact_path=None):
    
    ~\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\boto3\s3\inject.py in upload_file(self, Filename, Bucket, Key, ExtraArgs, Callback, Config)
        128     """
        129     with S3Transfer(self, Config) as transfer:
    --> 130         return transfer.upload_file(
        131             filename=Filename, bucket=Bucket, key=Key,
        132             extra_args=ExtraArgs, callback=Callback)
    
    ~\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\boto3\s3\transfer.py in upload_file(self, filename, bucket, key, callback, extra_args)
        283         # client error.
        284         except ClientError as e:
    --> 285             raise S3UploadFailedError(
        286                 "Failed to upload %s to %s: %s" % (
        287                     filename, '/'.join([bucket, key]), e))
    
    S3UploadFailedError: Failed to upload (path)\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgr5eaha2\model\conda.yaml to artifacts/1/5ae5fcef2d07432d811c3d7eb534382c/artifacts/model2/conda.yaml: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the PutObject operation: The Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of this issue. It is a tricky problem due to spanish characters, my system's user profile in "C:/" is "fcañizares" (Cañizares is my first last name). I have created another user named "fcanizares" and all is working fine. Hope you find this solution helpfull.

PS: Moral of the issue, get rid of the extrange characters!